# How to fix invalid entitlement for Core NFC Framework after Xcode update

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11, core-nfc

I have created an app which has NFC tag reading functionality. I have done some changes to it and uploading the new version to App Store. Everything was working fine until last week when I updated Xcode to 11.1. Now when I Archive it I have the following error saying.

"Invalid entitlement for Core NFC framework. The sdk version "13.1" and min OS version "11.0" are not compatible for the entitlement 'com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats' because TAG is missing in the entitlement.

I have done the following changes to my info.Plist file but the error still persists.
Any help will be appreciated.

Plist Changes

```
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
<array>
    <string>NDEF</string>
    <string>TAG</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So, removing NFC tag reading from capabilities and adding it again, which added an entitlements file. This fixed the issue.